# Finder not responding

Tags: macos, finder

My Mac is working perfectly but for the fact that Finder won't respond. Unless another app is running, my Mac's toolbar isn't showing up. Also, some of Finder's functions e.g. shut down, restart, and so many more are disabled. When I right click its icon, it says "Application Not Responding" or something along those lines. I have tried relaunching from the GUI, because the toolbar disappears every time I close other applications, I couldn't do it from the toolbar, and even the `killall` command doesn't work. I have to use the `sudo shutdown -r now` command to restart. Somebody help me please!

Answer (score 1):

I'd first start up in Safe Mode by holding down the Shift key at the startup chime; Safe Mode does some internal housecleaning.

If that doesn't fix it, I'd reinstall macOS.